# Does JMeter performance testing effect live websites

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

I have been  using my blog to learn JMeter and I wondered how risky this could be. For example if I load test a site ex:- randomsite.com(Which has limited resource where the website is hosted) with 100,000 users or more wouldn't it effect the website? Are there mechanisms to prevent such scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will affect your web site. Performance benchmarking tools do introduce load and are designed to stress test applications, websites and databases. The idea is to do this before you deploy your application, web site and other systems to know what your theoretical limits are. Also keep in mind by monitoring the systems performance with a tool you are also adding extra load. Thus the number you get from these tools are not always 100% accurate. Its better to know the theoretical limitations then not knowing at all.

One mechanism you can use to stop such tools being used in a malicious way is to run some intrusion detection system(IDS) on the network edge. These system will probably identify this type of activity as a DOS attack of sorts and then block the originating IP.

DDOS attacks makes things a lot more difficult to cope with. This is where 1000's of machines make requests small enough not to be picked up by the IDS as a DOS attack at the same target. The  IDS just sees a lot of small amounts of traffic,request etc coming from a lot of addresses. This makes it very hard to determine what is a real request and what is a request that is an attack.

Comment: Ok so in simple if we do this for facebook or google as testing they will identyf it as a attack and block it. Thanks bro!

Comment: IDS is but one way of limiting these type of things. Facebook and Google have teams of people monitoring their systems. They are pretty sophisticated and resilient if they were not they would not be so successful.